# One background image split between 2 divs

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, background-image

Struggled for a solution the first time so I am posting again with more info. Thanks in advance for your feedback.

On the website I am building at the moment I have 2 background images set to 2 different divs but they need to line up perfectly on all devices.

At the moment the background images line up at 1920px wide and smaller but once you start going larger than that it starts shifting.

Please could someone help?

Please see an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL1RA.jpg) that it should resemble

```css
.productTopSection {
  background: url("http://mcauliffe.testcre8.co.uk/assets/images/home/mcauliffe-brownfield-experts-homepage-about-image.jpg") no-repeat center;
  min-height: 895px;
  background-size: auto 100%, cover;
}

.mc-key-points {
  background: url("http://mcauliffe.testcre8.co.uk/assets/images/home/mcauliffe-brownfield-experts-homepage-key-points-image.jpg") no-repeat center;
  min-height: 895px;
  background-size: auto 100%, cover;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1921px) {
  .productTopSection {
    background: url("http://mcauliffe.testcre8.co.uk/assets/images/home/mcauliffe-brownfield-experts-homepage-about-image.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    min-height: 895px;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .mc-key-points {
    background: url("http://mcauliffe.testcre8.co.uk/assets/images/home/mcauliffe-brownfield-experts-homepage-key-points-image.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    min-height: 895px;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .productTopSection {
    background: url("http://mcauliffe.testcre8.co.uk/assets/images/home/mcauliffe-brownfield-experts-homepage-about-image-mobile.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  .mc-key-points {
    background: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="productTopSection g-py-200">
  <!-- Content Goes Here -->
</div>


<div class="mc-key-points g-py-200">
  <!-- Content Goes Here -->
</div>
```

Comment: Fix the snippet,is'nt working.And there is only TV-monitors that are 1920 pixels wide.

Comment: @djangotic thanks! Snippet is working now. My monitor is much wider than 1920px, that's why I am wondering.

Comment: Include an image that it should resemble

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.productTopSection {
    background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
    min-height: auto;
}
```

since then there is no content i think the above is the way.correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Sorry the snippet used doesn't have content because I didn't want to confuse the matter. Both divs will be different sizes and will have different amounts of content in them.

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not work, well, it doesn't matter, I'll try to understand you

1. First he trumpets to understand how it works

[image]

The **blue frame** is your div in full screen mode (one element for the whole page)
since the div has no height, you give it a min-height or fixed height (height property) in your case it works the same with only a background and until you put something in the div

At this stage, you need to understand that the height you specify does not affect the height of the image itself, that is, the min-height will not change until you put a lot of text in it (this is just an example, you can put whatever you want that has a height)

2. In the image I have demonstrated the background-size property with **100% auto** value.
   from the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) we see that we set 100% width and leave the height on auto also by default the bakcground-image has the same position (background-poistion: 0% 0%)

If you write it all like this:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
background-position: 0 0; // this is not required as this is the default, I am just using this as an example
```

we will get the result as in the picture above, where the picture will be stretched in width relative to the screen

well now we reduce the width of screen (div automatically starts changing width and taking the width of the screen)
[image]

what do we see? there is an empty space below! In your case you set the height to 100% and the width automatically

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

and yes, you shouldn't use multiple background image syntax in your case

```
 background-size: auto 100%, cover; // you have one background image
```

This is what your non-working result looks like:

[image]

**Note** that I can see that you are using center positioning, so you have two holes! With what I congratulate you!

What should you do? You must use an image (html **img** tag) instead of a background

Example:

```
<img aria-hidden="true" class="bg-fix" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/767/1200/800.jpg?hmac=lGBpi_Bt_UPPi17TX-TUBQitEe14QlbeSJ-GYhwZBvw" alt="">
<style>
    img {
        display: block; // Remove inline native space
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

or use media to control the div's height (use vh instead of pixels or css media queries)

```
<style>
    div {
        /*.....*/
        -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
        background-size: 100% auto;
        min-height: 60vh;
    }

    /* OR */

    div {
        /*....*/
        min-height: 875px;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        div {
            min-height: 500px; 
        }
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's not clear to me if you were planning to crop the image sides on mobile, I think this may help out at least - for something like this I think you can make it much easier by using an `<img>` tag in HTML instead of `background-image` in CSS.

The problem is getting the height to scale proportionally to the width so that the images retain their aspect ratio. What's happening in your code is the height is effectively being set to 895px with the `min-height`, it will not go higher unless you add enough content to the div.

So starting with mobile screens, your height is still 895px and the sides of the images will be cropped less and less until you reach 1920px in width (the image width). Once you go over this the image will start to stretch wider to cover and the top/bottom will start to be cropped. That top/bottom cropping while the images are centered is what causing the edges in the image to not line up. Because you're now lining up say 20% up on the top image to 20% down on the bottom one when you planned for 0% to line up.

So how does the `<img>` tag make this easier?

It adds content width/height to your container and allows the container to expand to fit the content, or force the content to shrink to fit in it. if you just throw an img in a div you'll see it expands the div out to the dimensions of the img.

But if you set the width to 100% on both the container and the img, it will fill the width of the container. The key being that the height will be proportionally set to maintain the aspect ratio and the div will expand in height to fit the img height needed and you will not have any top/bottom cropping so edges will line up.

Then you just need an absolute positioned container over the img to put your text content wherever you want.

If you were trying to crop the image sizes on small screens (which I think would look better). I'd suggest you use media queries there just to set some breakpoints where maybe the image is 120% width on phones and center - you'll still have that height though so if it's too high and you need to crop to bring the height down, I do have an idea for that but don't want to scope creep too much...

Here's an example with `<img>` - much less going on here and more straightforward IMO. And you gain more control - you can tweak this a lot to crop however you want at different media queries.

```css
.productTopSection, .mc-key-points {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.responsive-img {
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: absolute;

  /* just to get started with the content positioning */
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="productTopSection g-py-200">
  <img class="responsive-img" src="http://mcauliffe.testcre8.co.uk/assets/images/home/mcauliffe-brownfield-experts-homepage-about-image.jpg">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    Content Goes Here!
  </div>
</div>


<div class="mc-key-points g-py-200">
  <img class="responsive-img" src="http://mcauliffe.testcre8.co.uk/assets/images/home/mcauliffe-brownfield-experts-homepage-key-points-image.jpg">
  <div class="overlay-content">
    Content Goes Here!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems along the right lines and the background images line up perfectly. However the py-200 is being added above and below the image, so there are white gaps. And also the bootstrap container margin isnt working now. How would I structure my bootstrap container using the above solution? Thanks!

Comment: @MrRobboto the images no longer load.  Do you have another working example?